# Como dar scroll automático para o topo ao visualizar o rodapé da página?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css3

Estou fazendo um site, que possui algumas animações, e ao chegar na parte inferior do site pela primeira vez, deve acionar um evento onde a página volta ao topo, porém nas vezes seguintes (sem recarregar) o evento não acontecerá novamente.

Como poderia fazer isso?

HTML:

```
<header>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <div id="broca">
    </div>
</div>
<footer>    
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
header, footer{
display:block;
height:200px;
background:red;
width:100%;
}
#content{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:1500px;
background:blue;
}
#broca{
    width:50px;
    height:0;
    background:#000;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var $broca = $('#broca');
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > $broca.height()){
            $broca.clearQueue().animate({
                height: st } , 1000);
        }
        if( st == 0 ) {

        } else {
            $broca.show();
        }
    }).scroll();
})
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/9nzmdsm1/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare essa variável antes da função:

```
var counter = 0;
```

Acrescente isso:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
               if (counter == 0){
                   counter++;
               $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
        }
    }
});
```

Veja melhor aqui: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nzmdsm1/16/)

Comment: Ele quer que quando ir pro rodape dps da primeira vez, não volte mais pro topo. E seu código não faz isso.

Comment: Pronto, agora faz e de forma mais enxuta

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui está seu código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $documentHeight = $(document).height();
    var $windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var $scrollHeight = $documentHeight - $windowHeight;
    var $toBottom = false;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var $broca = $('#broca');

        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        if(st > $broca.height()){
            $broca.clearQueue().animate({height: st}, 1000);
        }

        if(st == $scrollHeight && $toBottom == false){
            $(this).scrollTop(0);
            $toBottom = true;
        }

        if(st != 0){
            $broca.show();
        }
        else{
            $broca.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Você pode testar aqui: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nzmdsm1/14/)

Comment: Tinha errado um operador, mas resolvi ja. Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, favor marcar como respondido minha resposta. Obrigado.